# Linux filesystem with metadata on SSD and file data on HDD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, filesystems, cache, metadata

When using an SSD (flash) cache on a HDD (hard disk) filesystem (using `bcache` or `lvmcache` on `dm-cache`), it can happen that some of the blocks necessary for some global operation (maybe a `find`) are aged out of the cache making access very slow. This is because typical filesystem metadata access patterns are small random reads where HDDs are particularly slow (more than 100 times slower than SSDs).

Forcing all metadata (inodes, bitmaps, dentries, journal and possibly small files) on SSD by design may solve the problem of slow and unpredictable access times, while keeping files (possibly those larger than some threshold) on HDD makes the solution workable even for large filesystems.
(If both SSD and HDD are mirrored, there is no elevated risk of data loss.)

**Are there any Linux filesystems able to use a small non-rotational device for metadata and a large rotational device for file data ?**

While `btrfs` is able to force one mirror of metadata to a SSD, it seems unable to force file contents out of the SSD. And I'm unsure whether it is able to read metadata only from the SSD. (Metadata is mirrored and thus also available from the HDD, but that mirrored metadata shall only be used in case of SSD failures.)

Answer (score 3):

In [ZFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS) you can use *Special Devices* to store metadata, deduplication tables, and optionally small files up to a user-defined size.

> ## Special Allocation Class
>
> The allocations in the special class are dedicated to specific block types. By default this includes all metadata, the indirect blocks of user data, and any deduplication tables. The class can also be provisioned to accept small file blocks.
>
> A pool must always have at least one normal (non-dedup/special) vdev before other devices can be assigned to the special class. If the special class becomes full, then allocations intended for it will spill back into the normal class.
>
> https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/man/8/zpoolconcepts.8.html#Special_Allocation_Class

So this can be used to accelerate disk accesses using an SSD disk. You can choose to mirror multiple metadata devices for redundancy, or just use the SSD as the only metadata storage. AFAIK when that special device is full then metadata will be stored in the main storage so things will work just as normal

> ## Special VDEV Class
>
> In ZFS 0.8 and later, it is possible to configure a Special VDEV class to preferentially store filesystem metadata, and optionally the Data Deduplication Table (DDT), and small filesystem blocks. This allows, for example, to create a Special VDEV on fast solid-state storage to store the metadata, while the regular file data is stored on spinning disks. This speeds up metadata-intensive operations such as filesystem traversal, scrub, and resilver, without the expense of storing the entire filesystem on solid-state storage.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS#Special_VDEV_Class

> ## ZFS Special Device
>
> A special device can improve the speed of a pool consisting of slow spinning hard disks with a lot of metadata changes. For example workloads that involve creating, updating or deleting a large number of files will benefit from the presence of a special device. ZFS datasets can also be configured to store whole small files on the special device which can further improve the performance. Use fast SSDs for the special device.
>
> https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/ZFS_on_Linux#sysadmin_zfs_special_device

---

Example on how to set up this

> ### Adding the special vdev to an existing zpool
>
> ```
> #implied stripe of mirrors, for this special device 
> zpool add elbereth -o ashift=12 special mirror /dev/nvme0n1 /dev/nvme1n1 mirror /dev/nvme2n1 /dev/nvme3n1
> ```
>
> ### Setting the Small Blocks size:
>
> ```
> # zfs set special_small_blocks=128K elbereth
> ```
>
> Or if you have a “videos” dataset like ours:
>
> ```
> # zfs set special_small_blocks=128K elbereth/videos
> ```
>
> [ZFS Metadata Special Device: Z](https://forum.level1techs.com/t/zfs-metadata-special-device-z/159954/1)

See also

- [ZFS and cache devices](https://serverfault.com/q/168326/343888)
- [ZFS Metadata: Special Device And You!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QI4SnKAP6cQ)
- [Why is nobody talking about the newly introduced Allocation Class VDEVs? This could significantly boost small random I/O workloads for a fraction of the price of full SSD pools.](https://www.reddit.com/r/zfs/comments/cm594b/why_is_nobody_talking_about_the_newly_introduced/)

Comment: This looks like it is impossible to force alle dentries (directories) to the SSD so a global `find` may still be slow when it comes to parts of the filesystem which haven't been accessed for long. Am I right ?

Comment: I don't know how ZFS stores the dentries but all modern Linux filesystems have dentry cache so most of the time it won't be a problem. Besides for global find usually a tool like [`locate`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/locate.1.html) is better

Comment: ZFS has [persistent L2ARC](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2020/02/zfs-on-linux-should-get-a-persistent-ssd-read-cache-feature-soon/) which help further improving some kind of lookups

Comment: While `locate` is helpful for searching for file names, it won't help if other metadata attributes like size or ctime are needed. And both the kernel dentry cache and the zfs ARC and L2ARC caches keep only what is recently or frequently accessed and thus can't guarantee fast and reproducible full-filesystem operations which this question is about. Examples of these operations might be complex `find`s, `fsck`, `rsync` or incremental backups.

Answer (score 0):

[Bcache](https://bcache.evilpiepirate.org/) is

> ... a Linux kernel block layer cache. It allows one or more fast disk drives such as flash-based solid state drives (SSDs) to act as a cache for one or more slower hard disk drives.

And its descendant [Bcachefs](https://bcachefs.org/), a modern filesystem comparable to Btrfs and ZFS [available since Linux 6.7](https://www.phoronix.com/news/Bcachefs-Merged-Linux-6.7), also supports multiple target device types: 3 storage + 1 **metadata** targets

> In bcachefs these activities are categorised as target options. Four target options exist which may be set at the filesystem level (at format time, at mount time, or at runtime via sysfs), or on a particular file or directory:
>
> - foreground target: normal foreground data writes, and metadata if metadata target is not set
> - **metadata target: btree writes**
> - background target: If set, user data (not metadata) will be moved to this target in the background
> - promote target: If set, a cached copy will be added to this target on read, if none exists
>
> [Labels and target options](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Bcachefs#Labels_and_target_options)

You can specify a special metadata device like [these examples](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Bcachefs#Usage)

```
# bcachefs format /dev/sd[ab] --foreground_target /dev/sda --promote_target /dev/sda \
    --background_target /dev/sdb --metadata_target /dev/sda

# bcachefs format --compression=zstd \
    --encrypted \
    --replicas=2 \
    --label=hdd.hdd1 /dev/sdc \
    --label=hdd.hdd2 /dev/sdd \
    --label=hdd.hdd3 /dev/sde \
    --label=ssd.ssd1 /dev/sdl \
    --label=ssd.ssd2 /dev/sdm \
    --foreground_target=ssd \
    --promote_target=ssd \
    --background_target=hdd \
    --metadata_target=ssd
```

However using an SSD just for metadata is usually not very efficient, because metadata constitute a very small part of the whole data set, so a 512GB SSD is only useful for huge block devices like 25600GB or more

See also

- [The bcachefs filesystem](https://lwn.net/Articles/655366/)
- [Bringing bcachefs to the mainline](https://lwn.net/Articles/895266/)
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Bcachefs, https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Bcache
- https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Bcachefs, https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Bcache
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcachefs, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcache

Comment: Using an SSD just for metadata is in fact inefficient if metedata is defined as btree only like bcachefs does according to your answer. But if metadata gets defined as I did in my question  (inodes, bitmaps, dentries, journal and possibly small files) this might change. While I love the idea of having a foreground and a promote target it looks like bcachefs does not support forcing  _all_ inodes, bitmaps, dentries and journal to the SSD which is what I asked for.